# Dynamical create formcontroll name in a form group

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I have a angular 2 form with form group like this

```
this.person = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:[],
      age:[]
      customAttributes: this.formBuilder.group({

      }
```

In this i want to add dynamic `formControlName` to `customAttributes`
That my be anything related to the person and it is a dynamic value.

Is this possible? and how.

can any one please help me

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What do you want to add?

Comment: how? i want to add dynamic formControllername

Comment: dynamic in the sense, you are receiving from api/service data.?

Comment: @PrasanthS yes  after some API call have some value like address,city,job.. this value is not stable and next API call it may be change . so i want to set these value to dynamicaly as formcontrollername

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Generic method which enable to add form control name and form group in you application.

Here is similar example is give which help to get you required ans 
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form/